# How to select HTML elements that do not have a specific attribute value?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Basically title, my html looks like this:

```
<th data-stat='foo'> 10 </th>
<th data-stat='bar'> 20 </th>
<th data-stat='DUMMY'>  </th>
```

and I tried using

```
x = [td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td') and not rows[i].findAll(attrs={"data-stat":"DUMMY"})]
```

but that did not work obviously. My desired output would only get the text from `data-stat="foo"` and  `data-stat="bar"`, which would look like:

```
x=["10","20"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `css selector` with pseudo-class `:not()` to select your elements:

```
soup.select('th:not([data-stat="DUMMY"])')
```

**Note:** *In your question you try to find `td` while there is only `th` in your example.*

Just in addition concerning your approach with `list comprehension` - You were close to a solution but could use `if-statement`:

```
[th.getText(strip=True) for th in soup.find_all('th') if th.get('data-stat') != 'DUMMY']
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ='''
<th data-stat='foo'> 10 </th>
<th data-stat='bar'> 20 </th>
<th data-stat='DUMMY'>  </th>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('th:not([data-stat="DUMMY"])')]
```

##### Output

```
['10', '20']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find easily on the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table = """"<th data-stat='foo'> 10 </th>
<th data-stat='bar'> 20 </th>
<th data-stat='DUMMY'>  </th>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(table, "lxml")
value_list = []


value_list.append(soup.find("th", {"data-stat": "foo"}).text.strip())
value_list.append(soup.find("th", {"data-stat": "bar"}).text.strip())
print(value_list)
```